# Strip plot with many columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

**How can I replicate a plot like the one below using ggplot?**

It is basically a set of strip plots, bound side-by-side. I came across it as an image in a publication, so I don't have the code that made it.

My data source (not plotted) would be something like a list of vectors, similar to those below, each of which can be of a different length.

`my_data = list(a=c(1,18,90), b=c(1,5,7,8,80), c=c(1,6), d=c(1,22,35,300))`

(That said, using a different data structure would be fine too - e.g. a dataframe with some NA entries)

[image: Stacked strip plots]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty close:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
IDs <- letters[1:16]
values <- sample(c(rep(NA, 100000), seq(1e-10, 0, 1e-10)), size = 1600, replace = TRUE)
test_data <- list(IDs = IDs, values = values)

df <- as.data.frame(test_data)
ggplot(df, aes(x = IDs, y = values)) +
  geom_point(shape = 95, size = 10) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(0.5, 16.5, 1), colour = "grey75") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.035, 0.035)) +
  scale_y_log10(expand = c(0.001, 0.001),
                breaks = c(0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0),
                labels = expression(10^-4, 10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 2))
```

[image: example_2.png]

### Edit

Here is a more suitable alternative for the data in your example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
my_data = list(a=c(1,18,90), b=c(1,5,7,8,80), c=c(1,6), d=c(1,22,35,300))
df <- stack(my_data)

ggplot(df, aes(x = ind, y = values)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = as.numeric(ind) + 0.45,
                     xmax = as.numeric(ind) - 0.45),
                 height = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(0.5, 16.5, 1), colour = "grey75") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.125, 0.125)) + # alter these numbers to suit
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I notice `geom_point(shape = 95, size = 10)` creates a horizontal bar that is fine for this data, but way too short for my data. Can I increase its length without making it really thick?

Comment: Yep - I've edited my answer to show another approach that's likely more suitable for your use-case